# How to change provider useValue on runtime in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-routing, angular-dependency-injection

The Entry Point for my application is like [www.mywebsite.com/context/token](http://www.mywebsite.com/context/token)

I have a Provider in AppModule which I use as a base path for all API calls :

```
{
 provide: API_ENPOINT_BASE_PATH,
 useValue: 'rest/apis'
}
```

My Requirement is to read the token from the entry URL of the Angular Application and add it to the provider value like : 'token/rest/apis'.

How can I read the value from entry url and dynamically update the provider value ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is even possible. You could use a closure instead.

Comment: use behaviorsubject as providervalue

Comment: @enno.void something like this ?   useValue: new BehaviorSubject  or first store it in variable and then assign it here